# What could go wrong or why could software stop working if the system where the software is running is updated to a faster system?

Tags: upgrade, cpu-architecture

I faced this question in interview. I could think of the following reasons:

1. Architecture dependent code may break while moving from say 32 bit
   to 64 bit machine
2. Some set of instructions may be upgraded to somehow break existing ones (but have feeling that processor architectures are
   backward compatible to avoid such issues)

I could not really think of any more reasons, can someone else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another SE site, perhaps Programmers or Workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to have software break on better hardware would be if there is a race condition bug.  On slower hardware it might never come up because the hardware conditions make it just slow enough, but on faster hardware 2 threads of a program could inadvertently end up competing for the same resources.

Comment: On similar lines I believe the timer implementation which may take into account CPU clock  may also break or behave in undesired way.